# Matlab if statement not following all conditions

Tags: matlab, if-statement

Apologies this could easily be a repeat question but I'm fairly confident that I haven't found the answer.

Doing some regression analysis in matlab with fitlm. I only want to look at the models were the r2 value good but not perfect (I have a few "self comparisions of a variable against itself). So I want to just look a the models where r2 is greater than 0.75, but not 1, and the thing I care about is significant.

```
%do the modelling    
mdl = fitlm(X,comp);

%plot the good models
if mdl.Rsquared.Ordinary > 0.75 && mdl.Rsquared.Ordinary < 1 && mdl.Coefficients.pValue(2) < 0.05

plot(mdl)

end
```

This line of code

```
if mdl.Rsquared.Ordinary > 0.75 && mdl.Rsquared.Ordinary ~= 1 && mdl.Coefficients.pValue(2) < 0.05
```

successfully filters out r2 less than 0.75, and pvalue <0.05, but mdl.Rsquared.Ordinary ~= 1 doesn't work (in that models where r2 = 1 are still processed), and neither does

```
if mdl.Rsquared.Ordinary > 0.75 && mdl.Rsquared.Ordinary < 1 && mdl.Coefficients.pValue(2) < 0.05
```

What could I be doing wrong? Why does it work for r2 >0.75, but not r2 < 1?

Comment: It would be good if you made the conditions explicit using brackets, so there's no ambiguity about which term the relational operators `<` and `~=` correspond to and which terms the logical `&&` correspond to. i.e. do `(x < a) && (y < b)`. If that isn't the issue, we'll need you to [edit] your question to show a [mcve] so we can reproduce and show a solution for your specific example.

Comment: “It doesn’t work” is a difficult thing to debug. Instead, post code that you expect to work one way, but works differently. Then we can easily explain what is going on.

Comment: The `~=1` might not do what you expect because of rounding errors. You cannot compare floating point numbers for equality (or inequality). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/7328782

Comment: Comparing floating-point values for equality is a recipe for disaster, but obviously that's not the whole problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo part of what I don't understand is that the line of code does filter out the models where r2 < 0.75, but then doesn't remove the r2 = 1 models. Like I see there's a common issue where "if 0.75 < r2 < 1" isn't valid, it has to be 2 statements. Regarding ~=, if that were the issue why doesn't && r2 < 1 work either?

Comment: @Wolfie I don't see how that would help... the if statement successfully filters out models were r2 < 0.75, but not r2 = 1... surely that's just a problem with how I've written the if statement?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to explain, after that if statement I just have a section of code that plots the "good" models... I just want to cut down on the trivial "perfect results".

Comment: If `r2` is almost 1, but not exactly 1, say `r2=1-1e-14`, then MATLAB will print it as 1.0000, and you will (correctly) think it is 1. But the comparison `r2<1` will be true. I see you already figured out how to properly compare, well done!

Answer (score 1):

Changing it to mdl.Rsquared.Ordinary < 0.999 seems to do the trick